# How to implement on to many relation ? datastore google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

my application have business entity, and each business belong to one or more category !
How should implement the relation in my database ?

I have two options,

first option :
(to store all the categories that belong to specific business, at the business entity.)

```
class business(ndb.Model):
      name = ndb.StringProperty()
      categories = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=category,repeated=True)

class category(ndb.Model)
      name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

the second option :
(to store all the business that belong to a specific category at the category entity)

```
    class business(ndb.Model):
          name = ndb.StringProperty()

    class category(ndb.Model)
          name = ndb.StringProperty()
          businesses = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=business,repeated=True)
```

which option should I implement ?

Another problem:

every business could have one or more image:
should I store the images in list inside the business entity :

```
class business(ndb.Model):
              name = ndb.StringProperty()
              imagesUrl = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
```

or create new entity for each image :

```
class image(ndb.Model):
        businessKey = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated = True)
        imageUrl = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I know that the entity size is limited to one mega! yes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decisions like this one usually depend on your usage patterns. In you case, however, it looks like option 1 is the logical choice, because there are many more business entities than category entities.

For example, if you need to know which categories a business belongs to when you retrieve a single business entity, you will have to run an extra query if you choose option 2. With option 1, this extra query is unnecessary.

Another consideration is the frequency of updates. If you go with option 2, you will have to update your category entity every time you add a new business entity (thus, two entities have to be updated, which impacts performance and costs). With option 1 you only need to update one entity.

Comment: thank you for your answer,I edit the question , could you help in my second problem !

Comment: A better solution is to store images in the Google Cloud Storage and store only keys to retrieve these images from the Cloud Storage. It is cheaper, faster, and images can be cached by browsers.

Comment: Yes Yes,but I am asking about Where to store the keys? shoud I store it in the business entity,or create entity for each image ?

Comment: Again, it all depends on your usage patterns. Do you need all the keys when you retrieve a business entity every time? Do you need all the images at once? Are all the images the same, or they play a different role (e.g. logo, etc.)? How frequently do you update the images? Data modeling is not a trivial process. You can start by storing all the keys together, but you should consider these questions for a permanent solution.